# How to set up networking in UML on Fedora 21 on VirtualBox?

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, user-mode-linux

### I'm trying to set up an user mode linux machine on my virtual machine with fedora 21, as a part of a school project. I've got it running, but I've no idea how to get the networking to work.

edit. additional info

I don't know if it will be relevant, but my IP adress on vbox fedora is 10.0.2.15.

I was mostly following this guide: http://hanez.org/howto-user-mode-linux.html

What do I do step-by-step:

```
tunctl -u root
ifconfig tap0 192.168.0.254
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
./linux ubda=./rfs eth0=tuntap,,,192.168.0.254
```

login on UML

try to do ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 up which gives mi OPERATION NOT PERMITTED

route add default gw 192.168.0.254 gives "network is unreachable"

route -n table is empty.

Results of ifconfig, iptables, pinging, etc.

pastebin.com/zXjQLiuc

Comment: Can you add more details?? Like what happens if you ping your gateway or if you ping 8.8.8.8?? What the results of ifconfig? What type of connection did you set up in your VirtualBox? etc..

Comment: Connection type in VirtualBox is NAT. As for the rest, I don't know if I can provide any details as it's basically my first contact with system other than Windows... When I get into UML and try to do anything it says stuff like "network unreachable" - I guess I'm doing it just outright wrong. Also, most of the guides mention something like eth0, but there is only enp0s3 on my machine.

Comment: Ok so the adapters are just named differently, but the information you provided really isn't enough to tell what the problem is. Can you ping your gateway and post the results in your question, then try pinging 8.8.8.8 and post the results for that as well.

Comment: I've posted some more details I could come up with.

Comment: so it looks like the problem is not with your machine. You can ping the router and outside your network. Now are you saying that your school's server is unreachable? If so, can you ping the server's IP and post it's results if you havent already?

Comment: That's not exactly like that. I'm doing it as a optional homework, and I was supposed to give my user mode linux access to the internet from it's host - which is a Fedora 21 virtual machine. I can't think of any reasonable solution right now, and I have only 4 hours left, so I think I'll just give up on that one. Thank you very much for trying to help though ;)